# Visual Studio Code: close suggestion box on `esc`?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just what the title says. Visual studio code suggestions are sometime useful, but when they are not, I can't close the suggestion box. You either have to type something and then delete it, or click somewhere else on the screen. Can it be configured to close the suggestion on `esc`?

Comment: Which "suggestion box" do you mean? IntelliSense, hover hints and code actions all close on `Esc` for me.

Comment: I mean the intellisense box. It does not close on escape, and I haven't changed any relevent setting. It only closes on mouse click, or typing a character

Comment: Hm, strange, definitely works for me... have you tried with default settings + keybindings? Could be something like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32520).

Comment: Can't try with default keybindings and settings, as I have changed many of them. I have no chorded *escape* however. The problem is, in keybindinds, there are multiple options for *accept suggestion*, *next suggestion*, but none to close/ignore the suggestion

Comment: Why not? Just back them up somewhere and then restore them later, it's just two plain text / json files.

Comment: Found it. It was because I had assigned *escape* to an action without a *when* condition. Thanks, you drove me to the right direction.

Comment: Does not work for me on a fresh vscode install.. I have swapped esc and capslock using xkb in gnome though... The habit of closing such popups with esc is so ingrained it's basically impossible to use vscode :D

Yeah... vscode does not respect xkb options(!!) pressing the physical esc button works

Comment: See this issue for a xkb workaround: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23991

Comment: for everyone else led here, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53136609/11107541

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux and you exchanged Esc and Capslock, then vscode seems to ignore this. As [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23991) documents, this is a bug that the vscode maintainers did not yet fix. There is a workaround that seems to work for most people: Go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings`. Search for `keyboard.dispatch` and set it to `keyCode`.

Comment: my VSC appears `Keyboard Options` and `Keyboard Overlay Timout` with check boxes and number input. One more thing, in my `settings.json` puttig `"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"` gives `Unknown Configuration Setting`.

Comment: Okay, strange. For me it works. But are you on Linux?

Comment: Ubunto 20.04.06 LTS