# How to exit IntelliSense suggestions in VSCode, and/or add suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in Visual Studio Code, and I would like to know how to exit out of IntelliSense suggestions. Whenever I press enter, the first suggestion is automatically selected, and this is causing me problems, so I would like to know of a way to exit IntelliSense before pressing enter. I know I could change the settings to not automatically select when I press enter, but I prefer using enter for most things so I'd rather not if possible.

My biggest problem is, I'm using Haxe and VSCode keeps automatically correcting "else", in an else statement, to the variable "elapsed". So if there's a way to add "else" to the list of suggestions that would probably work too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75215600/836330 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75215788/836330 for how to prevent the first suggestion from being selected so you can press Enter and have a newline inserted instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default keybinding to exit IntelliSense is <kbd>esc</kbd>

This is bound to the `hideSuggestWidget` command. You can change the keybinding as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!