# How to stop VS Code from automatically selecting the first suggestion on hitting Enter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosuggest

Whenever I type a Widget function in my flutter code and hit Enter, VS Code automatically selects the first parameter suggestion. The parameter is then typed on the same line when I actually wan it on the next line.

Is there any way to add an empty suggestion on the top so that I have to press the down arrow first to select a suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
```

This controls if suggestions should be accepted on <kbd>Enter</kbd> - in addition to <kbd>⇥</kbd>. The default value is 'on'.

[Customizing IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)

Answer (score 4):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75215600/836330 for more but you might be interested in one of the new suggestion `selectionModes` especially in your case `never`.  [Will be in v1.75, in Insidr3s now.]

With `never` although the suggestions may be shown none would be selected so you could <kbd>Enter</kbd> and have a newline inserted and continue with the suggestions on the next line.

[image: suggestionMode never]