# How to prevent VSCode from autocompleting words while I write code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I only want the autocomplete to work if I press Enter or select something from the suggestion dropdown. However, with my current settings, things are autocompleting while I'm typing code. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example of when this happens (what programming language and what are you typing?)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75215600/836330 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75215788/836330 - the `never` mode sounds like it is exactly what you want.