# visual studio code suggestion escape

Tags: visual-studio-code

how do I escape using a suggestion? ex every time I write a test the suggested text is TextDecoderStream and as soon as I invoke test it changes to TextDecoderStream(). It also selects TextDecoderStream when I hit enter and tab.

Comment: Literally hit the `esc` key to get rid of those suggestions.  If the suggestion popup isn't there it won't insert any of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to declare a variable name try to embrace it between brackets e.g. "[text]".
If you're looking for another solution try this: [Visual Studio Code: close suggestion box on `esc`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956148/visual-studio-code-close-suggestion-box-on-esc)

Comment: I'm not, in this specific example I'm unit testing. however it gives unhelpful suggestions all the time that I would like to escape without having to select it